# Read PDF tables with Dynamic Lines data

Tags: pdf, itext

We are facing few issues while reading different PDF files with Headers and Lines. I have used iText to convert it to Text and tried to read it based on labels. If we get all the labels and values in one line, we are good. Otherwise iText is not converting to string properly.

For example, I have "Lable1: Value1" in left box and then "Lable2: Value2" in right box. If we get multiple lines in right box like "Lable2: Value2 \n Value3", iText is converting it as "Lable1: Value1 Value2 Lable2: Value3". This is causing issues while reading.

Could you please suggest how to fix this and any other best way to process dynamic value PDFs.

Regards,
RJ

Comment: > any other best way to process dynamic value PDFs ... don;t try and process PDFs. Get the source data. You do realize that PDF is not a word processing format and as such there is no things like tables or paragraphs inside of it (unless the source PDF is a tagged PDF but that is quite different)

Comment: Basically @Kevin is right. But if you really have to process pdfs like that and need help, please provide sample pdfs and your pivotal code.

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for your response. I have the same understanding as PDFs are not for processing. But Our vendor is not able to provide the files in formats other than PDF. As of now, he is not sending tagged PDF. Is it a big code change to tag a PDF?

Comment: Sorry @mkl, i can not post the PDFs here as they are confidential.Let me try to post the screenshot.

Comment: I'm afraid a screenshot won't help as the identical visual appearance can be achieved using completely different techniques.